# jupyter notebook no me permite acceder a mis carpetas

Tags: python, jupyter

[image: screenshot]

Hola, es la primera vez que publico aquí, así que espero haber subido bien la imagen.

Lo que ocurre es que al abrir Jupyter notebook no me aparece mi carpeta "Desktop" (donde tengo mis scripts) ni "Documents", etc. No he podido resolver el problema porque no se como hacerlo. Pongo una captura de pantalla para que vean como me aparece.

De antemano muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Cómo lanzas jupyter? ¿No puedes lanzarlo haciendo doble-click directamente sobre un archivo de extensión `.ipynb` desde el explorador de archivos de Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Hola se que ha pasado mucho tiempo, pero  esto me ayudo, saludos

http://gidahatari.com/ih-es/como-cambiar-la-ruta-de-trabajo-por-defecto-en-jupyter-notebook-en-windows